# Using auto hotkey to swap Ctrl & Alt and implement Ctrl Tab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

While using AutoHotKey I wanted to setup a rule to swap the left alt and left ctrl.  I can do this by doing:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt
```

I then wanted to keep the 'alt tab' functionality bound do those physical keys, thus I tried

```
LCtrl & Tab::AltTab
```

In addition to the two uptop, yet it won't work.  If I put it like so:

```
LCtrl & Tab::AltTab
LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt
```

Then the tab will work, however the ctrl alt swap will be broke.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

[The hotkey documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) talks about wildcards

> Wildcard: Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down. This is often used in conjunction with remapping keys or buttons. For example:
>
> *#c::Run Calc.exe  ; Win+C, Shift+Win+C, Ctrl+Win+C, etc. will all trigger this hotkey.
>
> *ScrollLock::Run Notepad  ; Pressing Scrolllock will trigger this hotkey even when modifer key(s) are down.

So try this

```
*tab::
{   if(GetKeyState("LAlt", "P"))  
{   Send {LControl up}{Alt down}{tab}
    KeyWait, tab  
}else   
{   send {tab}
}      
return
}          
~LAlt Up::
{   send {lalt up}
return
}
LAlt::LCtrl 
LCtrl::LAlt
```

Answer (score 6):

I improved this slightly to fix shift tab not working, now you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> as expected where as before you couldn't (was frustrating trying to fix indentation(outdent) when coding) I may improve this more and get <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> working

```
*tab::
{   

if(GetKeyState("LAlt", "P")){   
    Send {LControl up}{Alt down}{tab}
    KeyWait, tab  
} else if(GetKeyState("LShift", "P")){
    Send {LShift down}{tab}
    KeyWait, tab 
}else   
{   send {tab}
}      
return
}          
~LAlt Up::
{   send {lalt up}
return
}
LAlt::LCtrl 
LCtrl::LAlt
```

Comment: This was the closest I could find on the net, but after copying your code above the (as written on the keyboard) alt-tab still didn't work for me (Surface Pro 3, 8.1).  Neither did the (as written) ctrl-tab.  Did you have any alt-tab style functionality after doing this?

Comment: Coming from a mac and switching to a windows machine for a job, I found no problems with the above script on a Lenovo T470.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem myself, was looking for a more straightforward solution. If you swap Alt and Ctrl using SharpKeys (or other registry remapping tool) from there it's a simple:

RCtrl & Tab::AltTab